# Change content of textarea with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using gridster widgets on my webpage.Each widgets have multiple images on it and a textarea.The textarea contains the links of image seperated by comma.The initial content of textarea is achieved from JSON.The images can be deleted from the grid.I want to update the content of text area as the images are deleted from the grid.(If I delete and image the link of that image from text area should go away).As of now I am getting a static content in the textarea.

My JS to delete the image and an attempt to remove the content of textarea

```
$('.removediv').on('click', function () {
    var textArea = $(this).parent().next();
    var text   = textArea.val();
  var imgSrc = $(this).prev().attr("src");
  textArea.val(text.replace(imgSrc, ""));

$(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();


});
```

But the above code is not capable of making the textarea dynamic.It only works when there is just one image.

My function which generate the widgets

```
for(var index=0;index<json.length;index++) {
    var images = json[index].html.split(',');
        var imageOutput = "";

        for(var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
        imageOutput += '<div class="imagewrap"><img src='+ images[j] +'> <input type="button" class="removediv" value="X" /></div></div>';
        }

gridster.add_widget('<li class="new" ><button class="delete-widget-button" style="float: right;">-</button>' + imageOutput + '<textarea>'+json[index].html+'</textarea></li>',json[index].size_x,json[index].size_y,json[index].col,json[index].row);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g3kxsac/2/) will illustrate properly.In Fiddle if you go on deleting the image the text are content remains same.I want it to change.

Answer (score 0):

You should just put the "serialize" code in a function and call that function whenever an element is deleted:

```
$('.removediv').on('click', function() {
    var textArea = $(this).parent().next();
    var text = textArea.val();
    var imgSrc = $(this).prev().attr("src");
    textArea.val(text.replace(imgSrc, ""));
    $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
    serialize();
});

$('.js-seralize').on('click', function() {
    serialize();
});

function serialize(){
    var s = gridster.serialize();
    $('.gridster ul li').each((idx, el) => { // grab the grid elements
        s[idx].html = $('textarea', el).html(); // add the html key/values

        json_variable = JSON.stringify(s)
    });
    $('#log').val(json_variable);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g3kxsac/10/)

Comment: I actually want to serialize only when the button is pressed.Bcoz I want to send the data only when button is pressed and not every time and element is deleted

Comment: Is there a way for just to remove textarea content dynamically

Comment: In the same way you fill in the data, you can also remove it with `$('#log').val('');`... I don't understand what you want to do..